# Why is font size in VS Code and VS IDE different, despite having the same values?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022

I have set the same font size in both programs (12) and used the same font (Source Code Pro SemiBold), both on a 100% zoom level.

In VS IDE, the font is larger than in VS Code.

I've tried to change the zoom level in VS IDE (2022) to match the size in Code but that causes the squiggly lines to become extra-small and ugly

This is the issue:
[in VS Code, the font is smaller than in VS IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJmSf.png)

Comment: Visual Studio and VS Code are different applications, written using different languages and technologies. They share the name but they are not related in any other way.

Comment: I thought "font size" was something that related to pixel height. Am I wrong thinking a font of size "12" should be the same (12px) across the entire system (minus of course zoom functions of apps and the system itself)?

Comment: Make sure that both use the same unit of measure. VS Code measures the font size in pixels but it is possible that Visual Studio measures it in points (it does not mention the unit of measure).

Answer (score 3):

One is measured in **px** and the other in **pt**.

You can check what the same value for X pt is in px here: http://pxtoem.com/

EXAMPLE: 9pt = 12px

**VSCode**: The font-size is measured in px.

**Visual Studio**: By default, the environment font is tied to a system font that appears as 9 pt Segoe UI.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/fonts-and-formatting-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2022